# Disable mod_cache to fix website

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, mod-cache

I am working on a website that runs on WordPress. The an error occurs when accessing the blog page that it displays the RSS feed (in XML) rather than the posts. After some research I found out the when enabling `mod_cache` this error sometimes occurs. I see when looking at the apache2 modules enabled `apache2ctl -M` it shows that `mod_cache`, `mod_mem_cache` and `mod_disc_cache` are enabled. What should I disable in order to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do ***not*** have a `CacheIgnoreQueryString On` directive, or that it's set to `off`. Also that you do not have a `CacheIgnoreHeaders Accept` directive. I'm not terribly familiar with WordPress RSS generation, but disabling caching altogether is going to be really bad for performance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually fixed this quite some months ago, I simply disabled the mod completely and that fixed it.